# Is Protractor the only solution to automate AngularJS web apps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, xpath

I am working on selenium WebDriver and now I came across AngularJS application. From past couple of weeks I am struggling a lot to find Xpath for dynamic web elements especially for handling Drag and Drop. After researching a lot on Google I found that Protractor can do the job easily as it contains many Angular tags (like: ng-bind/ng-model).
Is there any other way to figure it out?

Comment: What is your question exactly, about _Protractor_ or _any other way_?

Answer (score 0):

In the background, Proractor also used selenium and webdriver.

You can thiknk Protractor is a wrapper of selenium and supply some advantages when coding auto script if web page is AngularJS app.

1) One advantage is supply some locator API, like:

1. `by.model()` to find element by 'ng-model` attribute
2. `by.bind()'  fine elemet by`ng-bind` attribute
3. `by.repeater()` find element by `ng-repeater` attribute

But these locator API will be converted to css selector finally, you can directly use css selector to archvie samve goal

2) Second advantage is automatic waiting when it's Angularjs app
[image]

I never use this advantage, I suspect the automatic waiting can't wrork as expect in some conditions.

No matter you use seleium Java, Protractor, selenium-webdriver, webdriverIO or other tool/framework, you can't avoid struggling how to write xpath or css selector. So at this point Protractor not has huge benifit than others selenium related tool/framework.

For handling Drag and Drop, Protractor is also rely on selenium webdriver, so other selenium related tool/framework should also has API to do that.

Finally, Selenium only concern HTML in browser, no matter it is Angularjs, PHP, Sprint, Python, Ruby Web App, all of them will be convert into HTML when display in browser. So any selenium related tool/framework can auto test AngularJs app.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But my question is that I am experienced in JAVA+Selenium, But to automate Angular web apps I have to start learning Protractor which is based on javascript.

Comment: You can think Protractor is a wrappter above Selenium, So you use Java+ Selenium directly to automate Angular web app is workable tool. Using Protractor is not a mandatory choice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Its really helpful for a beginner like me.